# Use Dependency injection in WinForm Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, autofac

I am using autofac in this scenario in my winform application. Its the first time am using autofac  and will needing details answer to my question below.

I have the following code in my program.cs

```
ContainerBuilder autofac = new ContainerBuilder();

autofac.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).AsSelf().AsImplementedInterfaces();

Container = autofac.Build();

using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var writer = scope.Resolve<Application>();
}
```

In my Service i have the following code

```
public class A
{
    Iservice _service

    public A(Iservice service)
    {
          _service=service
    }
}
```

Now in my Form i need to call the service upon a button click. I can't seem to figure out how to continue as from here.How do i call the service now ? if i inject the interface in frmLogin constructor,i need to pass the interface as parameter there .Here my event code below

```
public frmLogin()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
public button_Click_Event(object sender,EventArgs e){

    //Service myservice= new Service();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `A` is the service, and you want to call methods from `A` in the form.

Your service should be like this:

```
public class A : IService
{
    [...]
}
```

IService should be:

```
public interface IService
{
    [...]
}
```

Your form can now take `IService` in the constructor.

```
private readonly IService service;

public frmLogin(IService service)
{
    this.service = service;
    InitializeComponent();
}
public button_Click_Event(object sender,EventArgs e) 
{
    // now you can call service.anything here.
}
```

Whatever `new`'s your form must supply the IService for the form now.